# Expressing a piecewise defined functions as a unit step function

Tags: laplace-transform

I am trying to express the following function as a unit step function so that I can use Laplace:

$
f(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       0 & : t < 1\\
       t^2-4t+5 & : 1\leq t \leq3 \\
       0 & : t>3 \\
     \end{array}
   \right.$

Is the following correct, and if so, is it a "valid" way to solve it:

$g(t)=U_1(t)[t^2-4t+5]+U_3(t)[-(t^2-4t+5)]$

$\implies \mathcal{L}[g(t)]=\exp(-s)\mathcal{L}[(t+1)^2-4(t+1)+5]+\exp(-3s)\mathcal{L}[-((t+3)^2-4(t+3)+5)]$

$\implies \exp(-s)(\frac{2}{s^3}-\frac{2}{s^2}+\frac{2}{s})-\exp(-3s)(\frac{2}{s^3}+\frac{2}{s^2}+\frac{2}{s})$

I appreciate any hints if I have done something wrong here, or if I can improve something!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct, but instead of trying to recast something as a multiplies of step functions, we could go straight to the integration.
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\} &= \int_0^{\infty}f(t)e^{-st}dt\\
&= \int_0^10\cdot e^{-st}dt + \int_1^3(t^2-4t+5)e^{-st}dt + \int_3^{\infty}0\cdot e^{-st}dt\\
&= \int_1^3(t^2-4t+5)e^{-st}dt\\
&= \frac{\partial^2}{\partial s^2}\int_1^3 e^{-st}dt + 4\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\int_1^3e^{-st}dt + 5\int_1^3e^{-st}dt\tag{1}
\end{align}
Finally, the result simplifies to 
$$
\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\} = \frac{4e^{-2s}\bigl[(1+s^2)\sinh(s) - s\cosh(s)\bigr]}{s^3}
$$
We have the derivatives in $(1)$ since $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial s^2}\bigl[e^{-st}\bigr] = t^2e^{-st}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\bigl[e^{-st}\bigr] = -te^{-st}$.

Comment: Thank you, Dustin! I like your solution because it is more understandable for me (a beginner). Just one more question: Are our answers the same? Can I convert my answer into yours, or did I do something wrong?

Comment: @Akitirija your answer is correct. You can convert yours into mine by using the identities $\sinh(x) = \frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$ and $\cosh(x) = \frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help!